# Having trouble while setting VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, tunneling, strongswan

I want to setup VPN tunnel between hosts, such that their subnetworks can connect each other. Ex:-

DummyNetwork ---> PC1 (HOST A) ------------- PC2( HOST B)------ >DummyNetwork

PC1 IP address : 192.168.32.109
PC1 dummy network : 10.10.10.0/24

PC2 IP address : 192.168.32.110
PC2  dummy network : 20.20.20.0/24

PC 1

```
sudo modprobe dummy

sudo ip link set name eth10 dev dummy0

sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 brd + dev eth10 label eth10:0

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo route add -net 20.20.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.32.110 dev eno1
```

PC 2

```
sudo modprobe dummy

sudo ip link set name eth10 dev dummy0

sudo ip addr add 20.20.20.1/24 brd + dev eth10 label eth10:0

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo route add -net 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.32.109 dev eno1

After this run ping 10.10.10.1 from PC1 and ping 20.20.20.1 from PC2. ping runs fine here.
```

Setting up VPN

As I am worked on ubuntu 16.04 i.e I used strongswan for setting up vpn tunnel

Install strongswan on both hosts i.e A and B

Sudo apt-get install ipsec-tools strongswan-starter

PC1

```
Sudo gedit edit /etc/ipsec.conf

And copy below text in it.

conn red-to-blue

authby=secret

auto=route

keyexchange=ike

left=192.168.32.109

right=192.168.32.110

type=tunnel

esp=aes128gcm16!

sudo gedit /etc/ipsec.secrets

And copy below code in it.

192.168.32.109 192.168.32.110 : PSK "pass”

Sudo ipsec restart
```

PC2

```
sudo gedit /etc/ipsec.conf

And copy below text in it.

conn blue-to-red

authby=secret

auto=route

keyexchange=ike

left=192.168.32.109

right=192.168.32.110

type=tunnel

esp=aes128gcm16!

sudo gedit /etc/ipsec.secrets

And copy below code in it.

192.168.32.110 192.168.32.109 : PSK "pass”

Sudo ipsec restart

Testing our Tunnel
```

From PC1

```
ping 192.168.32.109
```

From PC2

```
tcpdump esp
```

I am able to capture esp packets here.
 But running `ping 20.20.20.1` from PC1 , don't get ant esp packets on PC2. What may be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no IPsec policy that covers the traffic between the subnets `10.10.10.0/24` and `20.20.20.0/24`.  With the current config you only cover traffic between the actual IPs of these hosts (*left|right*). You have to define the subnets you want to tunnel with *left|rightsubnet*.  By convention *left*=*local* is assumed, so on PC1:

```
leftsubnet=10.10.10.0/24
rightsubnet=20.20.20.0/24
```

If you want to include the hosts' physical IPs you could include them (or the keyword *%dynamic*) in these lists of subnets (comma-separated).

There is also not really a need for dummy interfaces (just install the virtual IP on an existing interface). And routes are installed by strongSwan automatically in routing table 220 (check with `ip route list table 220`). Installing *ipsec-tools* is also not required to use strongSwan.

Answer (score -1):

Try flipping your left= and right= entries on PC2

```
left=192.168.32.110
right=192.168.32.109
```

Comment: That's not needed in this case as, by default, the _stroke_ plugin flips the options automatically if it looks like _right_ is local.